# Existing ESTA after new citizenship?

Tags: esta, dual-nationality, uk-citizens, eu-citizens

if a person fills ESTA and in the section for other nationalities doesn't disclose all the ones that they have, that might cause problems I would assume?

Though in a case where someone gets ESTA done and after that but before their planned travel they acquire a new nationality by naturalisation, would there be any problem with using the existing ESTA as technically you now have 2 nationalities which you haven't disclosed/informed the US of (but you also haven't lied as answered the question before you acquired the second one)?
Would one have to get a new ESTA done in this case or existing one would be fine and you can be happy you get to keep at least some privacy with US government?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

**You need to re-apply.**

> If you obtain a new passport or change your name, gender or country of citizenship, you will be required to apply for a new travel authorization. This is also required if one of your answers to any of the VWP eligibility questions changes. The associated fee of $14 will be charged for each new application.

Source: **[CBP](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1073/~/apply-or-change-information-in-the-electronic-system-for-travel-authorization)**

Comment: Does it define 'obtain a new passport'? It could mean either getting a new passport to replace an expired one or getting one for a new citizenship.

Comment: I would assume the definition to be *if the passport number you are traveling on is different from the one mentioned on the ESTA application*. That covers all those cases. But I don’t see it defined there.

Comment: @simonatrcl, the ESTA automatically expires when your passport does.

Comment: @HankyPanky but in a case where your passport hasn't expired, you're still using that passport to travel and it still has all the identification/passport numbers you have provided to them when asking for ESTA but you just obtain a different one from a different country because you have naturalised (even though not intending to travel on this new passport and still planning to travel on the first one)?

Comment: Simalarly to @simonatrcl, I'm curious whether "obtain a new passport" and "change country of citizenship" means you've actually changed from being a citizen from country A and now a citizen of country B only. Or it does cover the case of you're still a citizen of country A and now you've additionally became a citizen of country B also. The quote definitely covers the first scenario but not sure if it does cover the second one ... The VWP eligibility would also not change, especially if both countries A and B have visa-free travel to the US (both countries in this case are EU countries).

Comment: @kiradotee I'm afraid i don't have any more information on that definition. My own assumption would be that *country of citizenship* would include such cases as well. If some information to the contrary is provided by someone on this post, i'd be glad to remove this answer.

Comment: There is a question on the ESTA form where it asks if you have any other citizenships, you will have answered no at the time but if you did it again you'd answer yes. for the sake of $14 I'd re-apply.